# Controlling decimal places in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am working with loads of tables in Microsoft Word 2010. I would like to limit the numbers I have to three decimals places, along with rounding them.

For example: 0.1234 will become 0.123 and 1.6789 will become 1.679. It is a simple task but I wasn't able to find the way to do this.

Note: for numbers ending with zeros: I would prefer to have them as 1.3 instead of 1.300 if there's a way to do that!

Comment: Wouldn't Excel be better suited to something like this?

Comment: It definitely would, but I do not want to copy all the tables I have into excel and then back into word. I thought I might find some click here or there that would do the job, as this function exists in excel already.

Comment: I would actually like to limit and round all the numbers in the document to the nearest three-decimal number. Is that possible?

Comment: One option you could try is to load your document into LibreOffice Writer (http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) which supports number formatting in tables via **right-click -> Number Format...** then save it back to a Word document. Whether or not this will work will depend on whether you are using any features that LibreOffice doesn't support. Otherwise you will probably need to write a VBA macro as Word doesn't have any built-in support for this AFAIK.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I've been looking and got to this conclusion too. Maybe you want to write this an answer to help everyone benefit from that? Thanks for your help @James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do this in Word. There are a couple of options I can think of but neither are ideal.

1. Download and install [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/). Its word processor (Writer) has the option to set data formats in table cells, which can be accessed by highlighting the cells, right-clicking and choosing the **Data Format...** option. Once you are done you can save it back out to .docx format, although its possible you might lose some formatting depending on what Word features you are using. Once saved as .docx the data type information isn't saved so the numbers won't be stay rounded if you edit them later.

   [image]
2. Use a VBA macro to iterate through the tables and cells and round the numbers up. The following code should do roughly what you want I think, but it might need some tweaking. You can create a new macro by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, giving it the name `RoundAllNumbersInTables` then clicking **Create**.

```vba
Sub RoundAllNumbersInTables()
    
    Dim currentTbl As Table
    Dim currentCl As Cell
    Dim currentRow As Row
    Dim currentText As String
    
    For Each currentTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each currentRow In currentTbl.Rows
            For Each currentCl In currentRow.Cells

                currentText = Trim(Left(currentCl.Range.Text, Len(currentCl.Range.Text) - 2))
                
                If IsNumeric(currentText) Then
                    currentCl.Range.Text = Format(Round(currentText, 3), "0.###")
                End If
            
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Obviously though you have to be careful that this doesn't mess something up, so it's best to have a backup of your file.

Overall I would say it would be better to use Excel instead for this kind of thing if possible as it is much better suited to it.